# Vue doesn't render data

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I had a complex data structure and Vue handled it fine. Then I refactored it and suddenly nothing seems to work.  I verified that the data structure was correctly assembled but nothing displays.  Vue didn't report any errors and nothing is displayed.

After several hours I found that the Vue render system does not work when the data structure contains a circular reference.  To verify I defined two classes A and B.  Each can have a reference to the other.

classA.js

```
export default class classA {
  constructor(name) {
    this.name = name
    this.refB = undefined
  }
  get name() {return this._name}
  set name(n) { this._name= n}
  get type() {return 'classA'}
  get refB() {return this._refB}
  set refB(n) { this._refB= n}
}
```

classB.js

```
export default class classB {
  constructor(name) {
    this.name = name
    this.refA = undefined
  }
  get name() {return this._name}
  set name(n) { this._name= n}
  get type() {return 'classB'}
  get refA() {return this._refA}
  set refA(n) { this._refA= n}
}
```

Next define a Vue component that displays a list of class A. Construct the list in the mount lifecycle hook and be sure to NOT link the instance of classB back to classA.  Verify the following renders a raw display of each element of the classAList

```
<template lang="pug">
   div Circular References
      div ClassAList length: {{classAlist.length}}
      div(v-for="cA in classAlist")
         div {{cA}}
</template>

<script>
import ClassA from '../classA'
import ClassB from '../classB'
export default {
  data () {
    return {
      classAlist: []
    }
  },
  mounted: function () {
    let a = new ClassA('a1')
    let b = new ClassB('b1')
    a.refB = b
    // Uncomment the next line to create a circular reference in the       
    // data structure. Immediately, once this next line establishes the
    // circular reference the Vue render system fails, silently
    // b.refA = a
    this.classAlist.push(a)
    console.log('Console listing the classA list ', this.classAlist)
  }
}
</script>
```

Check the console to see the array is constructed as expected.  Now uncomment the line of code that links the instance of B back to the instance of A.  The console will continue to show the array is constructed as expected but the Vue render system doesn't like the circular references.

Is there a workaround?
Is there a way to get Vue to show some error message. (e.g. like JSON.stringfy does on objects like this)?

Comment: I see a warning/error in the browser console indicating the circular reference. [dev build](https://imgur.com/a/mRxSyk5) and [production build](https://imgur.com/a/9E5GLr2) (Vue CLI 3.5.1, Vue 2.6.10, Chrome 73, macOS mojave)

Comment: Thanks @tony19 for the hint.  I'm using Firefox and somehow the console became filtered with "4 filters".  I don't know what set these filters nor what exactly they filtered but they filtered out some critical error messages.  I've been spending a lot of time tracing problems in all the wrong places!  Now that the filters are cleared ... should be able to find the problems sooner.